# I am trying to change the color of a container onTap but for some reason it isnt working

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code that I used. I am trying to implement a UI where a quiztaker can see highlighted the option that they selected.
I am new to this please tell me where I went wrong?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedOption = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
              // onTap is here
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () { setState(() {
                  selectedOption = 1;
                  }
                );
                  },
                child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: selectedOption == 1 ? Colors.black: Colors.cyan,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Hello World',
                  style: TextStyle(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move 'selectedOption' variable to outside of 'build' method
because when call 'setState', build is called and variable is reset.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int selectedOption = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
              // onTap is here
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedOption = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: selectedOption == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello World',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current code `Container` color is updating only once. You need to change your code as follows to get the required output

```
return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
              // onTap is here
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isSelected = !_isSelected;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello World',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Instead of using the `int` variable you should use a `boolean` and update its state when tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Please move  **selectedOption** to state class. then setstate() will work.